# Executing a process from .NET application without UAC prompt

Tags: c#, .net, uac, processstartinfo

I have a scenario where I need to launch an EXE from my .NET application, but I can't get around the UAC prompt that pops up. The prompt is triggered even before the other EXE is launched - probably on the very call to `Process.Start`.

I use this code for launching the app:

```
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo(path, "params");
            info.Verb = "runas";
            try
            {
                Process.Start(info);
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
            {
                // Person denied UAC escallation
                return false;
            }
```

Both EXEs (my app and the other EXE) have this defined in their manifest:

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

How can I execute the other EXE without triggering a UAC prompt, and have it have the same access token as the calling application (so it can make changes to files in the app folder etc)?

Comment: I had no verb initially, and stuck it there after looking up a fix. Didn't help, didn't make things worse.

Comment: what is the filename of your second exe?  There are rules that trigger UAC for filenames like 'setup', 'install', & etc.

Comment: neither of those. I just named it "mytest.exe" and got the UAC again.

Comment: make sure you take out the runas, that will trigger UAC regardless

Comment: @shsmith good catch. You might want to post this as an answer so I could accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent a UAC prompt when launching a second EXE:

1) do not use `Verb = "runas"` -- that will give you UAC every time

2) do not use setup-like filenames for your EXE.  Here is the rule from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> Before a 32 bit process is created,
>   the following attributes are checked
>   to determine whether it is an
>   installer:
>
> Filename includes keywords like
>   "install," "setup," "update," etc.
>
> Keywords in the following Versioning
>   Resource fields: Vendor, Company Name,
>   Product Name, File
>
> Description, Original Filename,
>   Internal Name, and Export Name.
>
> Keywords in the side-by-side manifest
>   embedded in the executable.
>
> Keywords in specific StringTable
>   entries linked in the executable.
>
> Key attributes in the RC data linked
>   in the executable.
>
> Targeted sequences of bytes within the
>   executable.

Comment: Strange, I thought the manifest file takes precedence over the setup heuristics.

Comment: apparently it doesn't - that was the issue on my end