# How to start a process and avoid system confirmation?

Tags: c#, windows, security

I start a process:

```
Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = wFileLocation,
                Arguments = arguments + currentUrl,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

The problem is that windows asks me whether it is 
worth opening a file, it can be dangerous.
How to avoid this?

Is windows API (find window and imitate click on accept) can solve this problem?

Comment: You can disable UAC :) or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164782/executing-a-process-from-net-application-without-uac-prompt

Comment: If you could bypass UAC that easily by simulating a click, every school boy and his dog would be writing nefarious software

Comment: If my mouse can bypass UAC by clicking, why my dog can't?

Comment: @DragandDrop lack of apposable thumbs

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator) check this

Comment: This isn't about UAC, it's about running a downloaded application. See [Unblock File from within .net 4 c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374673/unblock-file-from-within-net-4-c-sharp).